# get total working hours from mysql with pdo

Tags: php

I want to get my total working hours.

Saved as started time and end time

```
$sql = "SELECT end_service, start_service FROM stage ORDER BY stage_id ASC";
$sql = $db->query($sql);

foreach($sql as $row) {
    $count = round((strtotime($row['end_service']) - strtotime($row['start_service'])) / 3600);
}

echo $count;
```

Comment: It looks pretty inefficient to retrieve every row and do the calculations in PHP when you could get the results at once in a single SQL query.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález do you have a example?

Comment: I don't know anything about your database engine or your column types (you'd think that using date column types to store dates is the obvious choice but not everybody likes that). But you can calculate sums in standard SQL with the `SUM()` aggregation function, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your not recieiving any database errors, you need to set a count outside your foreach loop which is added to in each iteration.

```
$sql = $db->query($sql);
$count = 0;

foreach($sql as $row) {
    $count += round((strtotime($row['end_service']) - strtotime($row['start_service'])) / 3600);
}

echo $count;
```